# How to handle Login with Google in NodeJS+Android

Tags: android, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-signin

we want to cerate an Application that includes Login with Google, in Backend codes I implemented the PassportJS Oauth2 Login strategy but I don't know how to connect an Android app to login with google;

now I have Login with Google across Web and it worked fluently.

now My question is when and how I can find users singed in the app and i want users to continue with my own Tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile apps should use the appauth pattern and there is a learning curve to understand it. I have an online tutorial + code sample you can run, which I hope helps you to understand the workflow: https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/